# How to export as default in index with compose?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I am having a problem.
Imagine you have a folder in which one you have several files.
Each file represents a component

So here I am :
File 1 :
- Component 1
- Component 2
etc ...

In this folder I have an index.js to export every component from the folder.

In every component I use react apollo so I use compose.

for example :

```
export default compose(
  graphql(loginMutation, {name: "login"}),
)(ConnectionScreen);
```

at the end of my component ConnectionScreen. The problem is when i do this

```
export Connection  from "./Connection";
```

it doesn't work even if i add brackets (if i try to export compose without default) React says it is not a component so i can't use my index.js in my folder.

Do you have any solution ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you clarify your file structure? You mention `ConnectionScreen` but we don't know where that fits in your files/directories.  It's a common pattern to have a bunch of files that use default exports and then an `index.js` to collect all of those and export them as named exports.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hello, exactly 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting `default's` from individual files and then gathering in index file can be cumbersome because you would have to first import default from file1, name it a certain way and then export that aliased name.

IMO, you should not rely mostly on default and rather use named import for being explicit in larger codebase.

In order to do that you would change your code somewhat like below:

```
const connected = compose(
  graphql(loginMutation, {name: "login"}),
)(ConnectionScreen);

export { connected as ConnectionScreen }
```

Then you would gather in index and then exporting all out as:

```
// index.js
export * from "./Connection";
```

Comment: Thanks dude, just amazing !

Comment: @jim2k glad it helped out, you can upvote it as well if you agree on the strrategy.